# Quick/Easy generation of CRUD pages & Data Access Layer in CMS

Tags: asp.net, subsonic, data-access-layer

I have a database that I would like class files generated from, and also a .aspx page generated which contains a listview to interface with the classfile for create/read/update/delete.  I have started to use Subsonic but am not sure how flexible the scaffold control is.  Also, LINQ seems like an option, but it would be nice if that was generated.

Ideally, I would have a DAL which was a set of database classes so I could fine-tune anything I wanted to, and also it would output a web form for the web interface with listview/datagrid that I could incorporate into the back-end but would be generated output so I could fine-tune it myself if I wanted to.

Thanks in advance.  The reason I am asking is because I'm working on a project independently and the data access operations are always the most time consuming part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Dynamic_Data)** is supergreat! Saw a really cool demo on MSDN Live about a month ago. Create a full .net 3.5 web site from a database in 1 minute!!! Same idea as Ruby on Rails, kind of.

And then you can enhance, configure and modify the parts of the site you want. Basically you get a LINQ 2 SQL layer + some scaffolding witch you then modify to your liking. A quick start for any data centric web project.

And the scaffolding part is probably going to be introduced to other parts of the .net framework - like WPF and silverlight - so this technology is something one should know.

And since it's part of the .net framework it's basically free, which isn't a bad thing either.

Comment: I used it for a project of mine for about 1-2 months. It's very difficult to configure it or customize the fields/columns but as long as you're happy enough with the default generated codes that's a good option!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com) - it's a great product! Not sure how well it does the ASPX side of things, but I'm aware that it does contain that functionality and at the very least does a bloody good job at generating a DAL as a .net project you can include in your solution.

Hope that helps :)